# Javascript eval fails to evaluate json when escape characters are involved

Tags: javascript, json, eval, rhino

I am using rhino javascript engine to evaluate the json. The Json structure is as following :

```
{"DataName":"111","Id":"222","Date":"2015-12-31T00:00:00","TextValue":"{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Daugherty\",\"ContactName\":\"May C\",\"ContactEmail\":\"may.c@gamil.com\",\"Total\":25,\"Phone\":\"111-111-1111\",\"Type\":\"Daily\",\"Notes\":[{\"Comments\":\"One\",\"Date\":\"2014-11-27T00:00:00.000\"},{\"Comments\":\"Two\",\"Date\":\"2014-11-28T00:00:00.000\"}],\"ImportComplete\":true,\"RunComplete\":true,\"CompleteDate\":\"2014-07-31T00:00:00.000\",\"Amount\":2400.00,\"ProcessingComplete\":true}","NumberValue":4444.5555,"DateValue":"2014-12-01T00:00:00"}
```

Since I am using Rhino js engine I **can't** use JSON.parse and JSON.stringify. 
As you can see the json has embedded json, this json I am getting from a .net web api which is putting the escape character '\'. I am trying to replace that escape character in javascript but no help.

Is there any way in javascript where we can replace that escape character and use '`eval()`' to evaluate the json.

Here's the code that I am trying

var json = '{"DataName":"111","Id":"222","Date":"2015-12-31T00:00:00","TextValue":"{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Daugherty\",\"ContactName\":\"May C\",\"ContactEmail\":\"may.c@gamil.com\",\"Total\":25,\"Phone\":\"111-111-1111\",\"Type\":\"Daily\",\"Notes\":[{\"Comments\":\"One\",\"Date\":\"2014-11-27T00:00:00.000\"},{\"Comments\":\"Two\",\"Date\":\"2014-11-28T00:00:00.000\"}],\"ImportComplete\":true,\"RunComplete\":true,\"CompleteDate\":\"2014-07-31T00:00:00.000\",\"Amount\":2400.00,\"ProcessingComplete\":true}","NumberValue":4444.5555,"DateValue":"2014-12-01T00:00:00"}';

var find = '\"';

var regex = new RegExp(find,'g');

var inj = json.replace(regex,'"');

var pl = eval('(' + inj +')');

Comment: Why do you want to do this? Why not just use `JSON.parse()` on the outer JSON, then use it again on the inner JSON? There's no need for `eval` or replacing of escape characters... is there?

Comment: So you can use JSON.parse, but you choose to use eval?

Comment: You can `JSON.parse` the whole string, then once it's an object, you can parse the smaller ones.

Comment: My bad, I have edited the post. I <b>Can't</b> use JSON.parse method.

Comment: @RushikeshR: Why not? What version of Rhino are you using that doesn't support `JSON.parse`?

Comment: 1.7R2, the latest version of 1.8+ is having facilities of using JSON.parse. And I am using a product for this, which has rhino 1.7R2 as its core engine. They are updating the engine but not till later next year. So need to make this working.

Comment: Can you post the actual code you've attempted in terms of evaling the above. Currently what you have in the code segment in your question appears to be a JavaScript literal object, and not a JSON encoded string. Seeing the code will help determine exactly what might be going on with your escape characters in the string.

Comment: I have edited the post, added the code that I am using.

Answer (score 1):

#### confusing backslashes

The problem you are getting is due to the fact of not fully understanding escape characters, when you are more than one level of "string" deep. Whilst a single slash is fine for one level i.e:

```
"It is no coincidence that in no known language does the " + 
"phrase \"As pretty as an Airport\" appear.";
```

If you take that and then wrap it in outer quotes:

```
'"It is no coincidence that in no known language does the "' + 
'"phrase \"As pretty as an Airport\" appear."';
```

The backslashes (if supported as escape characters by the system parsing the string) work for the outer-most wrapping quote, not any of the inner quotes/strings as they were before. This means once the js engine has parsed the string, internally the string will be.

```
'"It is no coincidence that in no known language does the phrase "As pretty as an Airport" appear."';
```

Which makes it impossible to tell the difference between the `"` and the `\"` from the original string. In order to get around this, you need to escape the backslashes in the original string, before you wrap it. This has the result of one level of escaping being used by the JavaScript engine, but still leaving another level remaining within the string. e.g.

```
'"It is no coincidence that in no known language does the "' + 
'"phrase \\"As pretty as an Airport\\" appear."';
```

Now when the string is parsed, internally it will be:

```
'"It is no coincidence that in no known language does the phrase \"As pretty as an Airport\" appear."';
```

> ignore the my random Douglas Adams quotes being separated onto more than one line (using +), I've only done that for ease of reading within a fix width area. I've kept it parsable by JavaScript, just in case people copy and paste and expect things to work.

So in order to fix your issue, your JSON source (before placing in the JavaScript code) will have to look like this:

```
var json = '{"DataName":"111","Id":"222","Date":"2015-12-31T00:00:00","TextValue":"{\\"Id\\":\\"1\\",\\"Name\\":\\"Daugherty\\",\\"ContactName\\":\\"May C\\",\\"ContactEmail\\":\\"may.c@gamil.com\\",\\"Total\\":25,\\"Phone\\":\\"111-111-1111\\",\\"Type\\":\\"Daily\\",\\"Notes\\":[{\\"Comments\\":\\"One\\",\\"Date\\":\\"2014-11-27T00:00:00.000\\"},{\\"Comments\\":\\"Two\\",\\"Date\\":\\"2014-11-28T00:00:00.000\\"}],\\"ImportComplete\\":true,\\"RunComplete\\":true,\\"CompleteDate\\":\\"2014-07-31T00:00:00.000\\",\\"Amount\\":2400.00,\\"ProcessingComplete\\":true}","NumberValue":4444.5555,"DateValue":"2014-12-01T00:00:00"}';
```

You should find the above will `eval` directly, without any replacements.

In order to achieve the above programatically, you will have to see what the .NET system you are using offers in the way of escaping backslashes. I mainly work with PHP or Python on the server side. Using those languages you could use:

> the `$s` and `s` strings below have been cropped for brevity.

```
<?php
$s = '{"DataName":"111","Id":"222"...';
$s = str_replace("\\", "\\\\", $s);
echo "var json = '$s';";
```

or ...

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
s = r'{"DataName":"111","Id":"222"...'
s = s.replace("\\", "\\\\")
print "var json = '" + s + "';"
```

#### another solution

It all depends on how you are requesting the content you are wrapping in the string in JavaScript. If you have the ability to write out your js from the server side (most likely with .NET). Like I have shown above with PHP or Python, you don't need to wrap the content in a string at all. You can instead just output the content without being wrapped in single quotes. JavaScript will then just parse and treat it as a literal object structure:

```
var jso = {"DataName":"111","Id":"222","Date":"2015-12-31T00:00:00","TextValue":"{\"Id\":\"1\",\"Name\":\"Daugherty\",\"ContactName\":\"May C\",\"ContactEmail\":\"may.c@gamil.com\",\"Total\":25,\"Phone\":\"111-111-1111\",\"Type\":\"Daily\",\"Notes\":[{\"Comments\":\"One\",\"Date\":\"2014-11-27T00:00:00.000\"},{\"Comments\":\"Two\",\"Date\":\"2014-11-28T00:00:00.000\"}],\"ImportComplete\":true,\"RunComplete\":true,\"CompleteDate\":\"2014-07-31T00:00:00.000\",\"Amount\":2400.00,\"ProcessingComplete\":true}","NumberValue":4444.5555,"DateValue":"2014-12-01T00:00:00"};
```

This works because JSON is just a more strict version of a JavaScript Object, and the quote/escape level you already have will work fine.

> The only downside to the above solution is that you have to implicitly trust the source of where you are getting this data from, and it will always have to be well formed. If not, you could introduce parse errors or unwanted js into your code; which could be avoided with an `eval`/`JSON.parse` system.